# Add multiple json objects to table in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a JSON block thats formatted like this:

```
{
  "name": "somename"
  "rank": "50"
  "members": {
      "10": {
         "name": "Doug",
         "Age": "21",
         "Location": "USA"
      },
      "11": {
         "name": "Bob",
         "Age": "20",
         "Location": "CA"
      }
  }
}
```

How do I get each ID of "members" and then get the data inside?

I tried something like this but no luck

```
Object.keys(users[0].members).map((member, value) => (
        <Tr key={users[0].members[member]}>
          <Td>
            <HStack spacing="3">
              <Checkbox />
              <Avatar name={users[0].members[member].name}
```

Answer (score 0):

[here you can see the live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-darkness-eli2sf?file=/src/App.js:0-1302)

[Object entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
export default function App() {
  const data = {
    name: "somename",
    rank: "50",
    members: {
      "10": {
        name: "Doug",
        Age: "21",
        Location: "USA"
      },
      "11": {
        name: "Bob",
        Age: "20",
        Location: "CA"
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
          return (
            <>
              {typeof value === "object" ? (
                Object.entries(value).map(([key1, value1]) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      {Object.entries(value1).map(([key2, value2]) => {
                        return (
                          <tr>
                            <td>{`${key2}`}</td>
                            <td>{`${value2}`}</td>
                          </tr>
                        );
                      })}
                    </>
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                ''
              )}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay I almost have it but there's a bunch of undefined entries in my list. I only want the stuff in the members block.. https://i.imgur.com/RiQEzhq.png

Comment: You have to remove the `key` and `value`, so there will be only members data show, I have updated the answer. you can check now,